# Let's delete the list-of-photo-competitions question

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This is one of those community-wiki experiment questions that I think pretty clearly didn't work out. It's out of date, not very comprehensive, and attracts spam.

[What are some good online photo challenges?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/what-are-some-good-online-photo-challenges)

I think we'd be better off just closing and deleting it.

Comment: I agree, that at the very least it should be closed. I'll let the community speak, and act accordingly.

Comment: Agree.  Most of those are just links to the main site, no description, out-of-date, and easily found with a web search.

Comment: Three votes so far. Lets hope we have at least 5 people who read meta :P

Comment: I cast the last vote; not as a moderator, but as the 5th user. That is a pretty canonical example of why we tend to find such *let's-build-a-collection-of-links* so problematic in this format. Thank you for raising the issue.

Comment: +1 Vote from me if that helps :)